# Training Computer Vision OCR

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I setup the Azure Computer Vision Service and used in my app.  When I tried performing OCR on some images, it didn't recognize all the text (i.e. leaving out "S" in "cups").
Can it be trained/retrained in OCR when text isn't recognized correctly?

Comment: Which OCR operation did you use in your app? RecognizeText, or Read? Can you also provide a sample image?

Comment: I was using RecognizePrintedTextAsync and the image https://moderatorsampleimages.blob.core.windows.net/samples/sample2.jpg.  It didn't recognize the 'S' in "ourselves" on the last line.  Also, recognized the period as a comma.

Comment: Looks like you are in fact using "OCR" operation, not "RecognizeText" or "BatchRead". I will fill a reply to guide you to got the right results

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the case when OCR tools can detect everything. You can try preprocessing some images before sending them to the azure.
[Preprocessig](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-pre-processing-c1aec0be3edf)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image and info you provided, I quickly checked the output of Computer Vision API which has several operations for text processing:

- OCR: the original one, synchronous
- Recognize Text: the 2nd one, asynchronous, which will be deprecated for the last one
- Batch Read (2.0 & 2.1) > Read (3.0): the latest one, asynchronous also.

In terms of results quality, Read operation is better, especially for rotated items and other cases.

Here is a sample of the output of each one with your image (https://moderatorsampleimages.blob.core.windows.net/samples/sample2.jpg), generated with Cognitive Workbench [website](https://cognitive-workbench.azurewebsites.net/vision/computer-vision), an open-source demo of Cognitive Services.

### OCR

[image: Ocr]

You can see some errors:

- there is a "*" after "CAPABLE"
- "OURSELVE" is missing the "S"
- The last period is a comma

### Recognize Text

[image: RecognizeText]

Here the only issue is the missing period at the end

### Batch Read

[image: BatchRead]

Here the only issue is the missing period at the end

Conclusion: use Read 3.0 which is now Generally Available. API Link: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. Per my original question, can any of these functions be trained/retrained?

Comment: No they cannot be trained